# Disappearing text

Tags: android, textview, nexus-7

When I change text font in `Activity`:

```
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "CALIBRIB.TTF");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
```

I can see it in new style on emulator but it disappear on my Nexus 7 (4.4.2).
Font is placed in `Assets`

I have similar problem with picture. I can't see in on Nexus, but on Emulator is okey.

Comment: Similar code is working fine for me, both on emulator and on my Nexus 7. The only change is that I'm working with an .otf font.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the font in Nexus 5 
It workes, you should go for the .otf rather than ttf one.